# Vega: Cumulative Count Bar-Chart

Tags: bar-chart, reduce, vega, vega-lite

Let's say we have the following data:

```
"data": [
    {
        "name": "table",
        "values": [
            {
                "key": 1448924400000,
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key": 1448924400001,
                "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
                "key": 1448924400002,
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key": 1448924400003,
                "doc_count": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to render the following bar chart with VEGA from these data:
[image]

1. The first bar (named `>= 1` on x axis) represents the number of documents in `"data"` array for which the following condition is true: `"doc_count" >= 1`
2. The second bar (named `>= 2` on x axis) are the count of documents filtered by predicate `"doc_count" >= 2`
3. The third bar (named `>= 3` on x axis) is the number of elements in data array for which it is true that `"doc_count" >= 3`

I have looked through VEGA documentation and all of its transforms, but I still cannot understand how can I build that kind of a bar chart. I would appreciate any help either direct or indirect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By traversing documentation and reading each and every transform there is, I have finally found a combination of transforms that calculates cumulative sum.

Here is how it's done

```
"data": [
    {
        "name": "table",
        "values": [
            {
                "key": 1448924400000,
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key": 1448924400001,
                "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
                "key": 1448924400002,
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key": 1448924400003,
                "doc_count": 3
            }
        ],
        "transform": [
          {
            "type": "aggregate",
            "groupby": [ "doc_count" ]
          },
          {
            "type": "window",
            "sort": {"field": "doc_count", "order": "descending"},
            "ops": ["sum"],
            "fields": ["count"]
          }
      ]
    }
]
```